# Can dynamic method in outer block be accessed in child block? - Ruby Meta Programming

Tags: ruby

I have a DSL that allows me to write ruby code dynamically.

The `Outer` class takes a custom block of code to be processed.

There is also a well-known DSL method called `settings` which can take its own block of code for configuration purposes.

I want to be able to create reusable methods in the other block and have them available from within the inner block.

While writing the sample code for this post, I stumbled upon a usage that works by assigning `self` to a `variable` in the outer scope and calling the method on the `variable` in the child scope.

I would prefer to NOT need to assign self to a variable and I noticed that if I tried to do something similar in RSPEC, then I don't need to use `variable` = `self`, I can define methods in parent blocks and they are available in child blocks, see the last example.

### Classes

```
class Settings
  attr_accessor :a
  attr_accessor :b
  attr_accessor :c

  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

class Outer
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def build_settings(&block)
    Settings.new(&block)
  end
end
```

### Run the code

```
Outer.new do

  # Create a method dynamically in the main block
  def useful_method
    '** result of the useful_method **'
  end

  x = self

  settings = build_settings do
    self.a = 'aaaa'
    self.b = useful_method()    # Throws exception
    self.c = x.useful_method()  # Works
  end

end
```

### Run the code (with detailed logging)

```
# Helper to colourize the console log
class String
  def error;          "\033[31m#{self}\033[0m" end
  def success;        "\033[32m#{self}\033[0m" end
end

# Run code with detailed logging
Outer.new do

  # Create a method dynamically in the main block
  def useful_method
    '** result of the useful_method **'
  end

  puts "respond?: #{respond_to?(:useful_method).to_s.success}"

  x = self

  settings = build_settings do
    puts "respond?: #{respond_to?(:useful_method).to_s.error}"
    self.a = 'aaaa'
    begin
      self.b = useful_method().success
    rescue
      self.b = 'bbbb'.error
    end
    begin
      self.c = x.useful_method().success
    rescue
      self.c = 'cccc'.error
    end
  end

  puts "a: #{settings.a}"
  puts "b: #{settings.b}"
  puts "c: #{settings.c}"

end
```

### Console Log from the running code

- Assignment to `b` throws an exception
- Assignment to `c` works fine

[image]

### Sample in RSpec where you don't need to assign `self`

Why can I access the usefull_method in the RSpec DSL, but not in my own.

```
RSpec.describe 'SomeTestSuite' do
  context 'create method in this outer block' do
    def useful_method
      'david'
    end

    it 'use outer method in this inner block' do
      expect(useful_method).to eq('david')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the `Outer` instance to `Settings.new`:

```
class Outer
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def build_settings(&block)
    Settings.new(self, &block)
    #            ^^^^
  end
end
```

and from within `Settings` use [`method_missing`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/BasicObject.html#method_missing-method) to delegate undefined method calls to `outer`:

```
class Settings
  attr_accessor :a
  attr_accessor :b
  attr_accessor :c

  def initialize(outer, &block)
    @outer = outer
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  private

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    return super unless @outer.respond_to?(name)

    @outer.public_send(name, *args, &block)
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(name, include_all = false)
    @outer.respond_to?(name, include_all) or super
  end
end
```

This way, `useful_method` can be called without an explicit receiver.

Comment: nice, I'll try that out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [Forwardable#def_delegator](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html#method-i-def_delegator) for this.

We begin by creating the classes `Outer` and `Settings`.

```
class Outer
  attr_reader :settings

  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def build_settings(&block)
    @settings = Settings.new(&block)
  end
end
```

```
class Settings
  attr_accessor :a
  attr_accessor :b
  attr_accessor :c

  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

I have included an instance variable `@settings` in `Outer` to hold an instance of `Settings` that will be created dynamically by `Outer#build_settings`.

We now create an instance of `Outer` with a block.

```
require 'forwardable'

outer = Outer.new do
  def useful_method
    '** result of the useful_method **'
  end

  Settings.extend Forwardable
  Settings.public_send(:attr_accessor, :outer)
  Settings.public_send(:def_delegator, :@outer, :useful_method)
  x = self

  settings = build_settings do
    self.outer = x
    self.a = 'aaaa'
    self.b = useful_method
  end
end
  #=> #<Outer:0x00007ffa6f9da320 @settings=#<Settings:0x00007ffa6f9d8318
  #     @a="aaaa", @outer=#<Outer:0x00007ffa6f9da320 ...>,
  #     @b="** result of the useful_method **">>
```

As you see, the following operations are performed by the block.

- the instance method `Outer#useful_method` is created
- `extend` is used to include `Forwardable` in `Settings`' singleton class
- read and write accessors for `@outer` are created in `Settings`
- calls to the instance method `useful_method` in `Settings` are delegated to the value of `@outer`, causing `Outer#useful_method` to be invoked
- an instance of `Settings` is created and its instance variables, `@outer`, `@a` and `@b`, are initialized, with `@outer` being set equal to the instance of `Outer` just created.

We can now retrieve the instance of `Settings` just created and examine the values of its instance variables.

```
settings = outer.settings
  #=> #<Settings:0x00007ffa6f9d8318 @a="aaaa",
  #     @outer=#<Outer:0x00007ffa6f9da320
  #     @settings=#<Settings:0x00007ffa6f9d8318 ...>>,
  #     @b="** result of the useful_method **">
```

```
settings.outer
  #=> #<Outer:0x00007ffa6f9da320 @settings=#<Settings:0x00007ffa6f9d8318
  #     @a="aaaa", @outer=#<Outer:0x00007ffa6f9da320 ...>,
  #     @b="** result of the useful_method **">>
settings.a
  #=> "aaaa" 
settings.b
  #=> "** result of the useful_method **"
```